# The meaning of dont be flip with me

Tags: american-english

[image]

This text is from the book "Greed".
What is meant by dont be flip with me?

Comment: For those users working with screen readers or other environments where images are not visible, you should add a text transcript in addition.  That said, I think *flip* is sometimes used in place of *flippant* meaning imperinent, lacking manners.  I'll look for a reference and answer later if possible.

Comment: The question will end up getting closed without the quote as text. Google has this, no need to ask here: https://www.google.com/search?q=don%27t+be+flip+meaning

Answer (score 2):

don't be **flip**
adj  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/flip)

> marked by casual disrespect

Synonyms:
    impudent, insolent, snotty-nosed, disrespectful

To be flip in in conversation is to be rude, insolent and disrespectful

As in:

> You don’t want to be flip about how you do this,” Rasmussen told
>   Variety in an interview last week. Reuters 2018

[Etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/flippant#etymonline_v_8893):

**flip** from flippant (adj.)

> c. 1600, "talkative, nimble in talk;" 1670s, "displaying unbecoming
>   levity," apparently an extended form of flip (v.). The ending is
>   perhaps modeled on other adjectives in -ant or a relic of the Middle
>   English present participle ending -inde. Shortened form flip is
>   attested from 1847.